# Stack Overflow in Chrome from custom event function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've been working on a webkit specific library and in my testing I accidentally put two parameters in the wrong order, and somehow that caused a stack overflow rather than an error. I wanted to see if perhaps the community could provide me with some insight to why this might be causing a stack overflow in Chrome before I filed a bug.

```
var fn = function (eventType, element, callback) {
    var filter = function(eventType, element, callback) {
        var length = element.length;
        for(var i=0;i<length;i++) {
            fn(eventType, element[i], callback);
        }
    };
    if ( element && element.nodeName || element === window ) {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if (element && element.length) {
        filter(eventType, element, callback);
    }
};
```

I've tested this against Chrome stable and Canary and it throws the same error on both. The issue occurs when you call it like this: `fn([],"string",function() {})` as opposed to `fn("string",[],function() {})`

What I've discovered is the second parameter needs to be a non empty string, but other than that the first and third parameter are irrelevant when the second is a non-empty string.

I've also never filed a bug before, which is why I thought I would ask the community if they could assist me in finding why this is a bug, or why it isn't a bug, before I did anything.

The function is a modified version of the one at the start of this nettuts+ article. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't actually cause a stack overflow. If you replace the `js5.addEvent(...)` line with `console.log(element[i]);` the output in the console is each of characters in the element string variable. See http://jsfiddle.net/WaDWY/

Although from following the link I believe that line of code might be `fn(...)` instead. What this does is cause an infinite recursion calling filter, fn, filter, fn over and over until the maximum stack size is reached. See: http://jsfiddle.net/WaDWY/1/

This is would be expected and not a bug.

Comment: Oops, my bad with the js5.addEvent line still staying in there, I ported it directly from my library and neglected to test it. It should be a recursive call to itself. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

As well thank you for the explanation, it makes perfect sense to me. I know how to make simple changes to my if statements to prevent unecessary recursion, I was just curious about the source of the error.